# Serializing a dynamic list of XMLArrayItems in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, api, serialization

I'm having the hardest time deserializing an XMLArray, because the XMLArray isn't built well. Sadly, I can't change the response from the server (API Integration), so I have to make my objects match theirs. When I query the server, I get back in XML:

```
<instrument>
    <reqs>
        <party_middle_name>optional</party_middle_name>
        <party_first_name>optional</party_first_name>
        <party_suffix>optional</party_suffix>
        <party_last_name>optional</party_last_name>
        <party_marital_status>optional</party_marital_status>
    </reqs>
    <name>ABANDONMENT</name>
    <countyInstrument>true</countyInstrument>
</instrument>
```

They got half of it right.... but the party_middle_name, party_first_name, etc can have more XMLArrayItems than presented. And I have to account for Array Items randomly showing up or not showing up. I also don't have an extensive list of ALL the optional elements that could show up, so I can't just write a collection of nullable items and define each.

So far, I have:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class InstrumentList
    Private Property _name As String
    Private Property _countyInstrument As Boolean
    Private Property _reqsList As List(Of ReqsList)

    <XmlElement("name")> _
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return Me._name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement("countyInstrument")> _
    Public Property CountyInstrument() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._countyInstrument
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me._countyInstrument = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlArray("reqs"), XmlArrayItem(" [ MISSING PIECE HERE ] ")> _
    Public Property ReqsList() As List(Of ReqsList)
        Get
            Return Me._reqsList
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of ReqsList))
            Me._reqsList = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class


<Serializable()> _
Public Class ReqsList
    Private Property _requirement As String

    <XmlText> _
    Public Property Requirement() As String
        Get
            Return Me._requirement
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._requirement = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I need to create dynamic element based on the XMLArrayItem's XML Element name, and then pair it with its XMLText. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so hopefully, maybe, this can help someone else. There was no eloquent way to do this, but I came up with a way to create some sort of solution.

First we took the Xml Stream back from the server, and converted it into an XmlDocument. Then we picked out all the XmlNodes that I want to fix and created an XmlNodeList. We, then, step through the XmlNodeList and correct each ChildNode. We replace the ChildNodes, and return back a String of the InnerXML.

I then have a function I've written to Parse XML Stream's into the objects I want.

So my Property looks like:

```
    <XmlArray("reqs"), XmlArrayItem("req")> _
    Public Property ReqsList() As List(Of ReqItem)
        Get
            Return Me._reqsList
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of ReqItem))
            Me._reqsList = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

And my FixInstrumentReqs Function looks like:

```
    Public Shared Function FixInstrumentReqs(stream As String) As String
        Dim xml As New XmlDocument()
        xml.LoadXml(stream)

        Dim xmlNodes As XmlNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/xml/ServiceResponse/List/instrument/reqs")

        For Each x As XmlElement In xmlNodes
            For i As Integer = 0 To x.ChildNodes.Count Step 1
                Dim y As XmlElement = x.ChildNodes.Item(i)
                If IsNothing(y) = False Then
                    Dim _new As XmlElement = xml.CreateElement("req")
                    Dim attr As XmlAttribute = xml.CreateAttribute("name")
                    attr.Value = y.Name
                    _new.SetAttributeNode(attr)
                    _new.InnerText = y.InnerText
                    y.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(_new, y)
                End If
            Next
        Next

        stream = xml.InnerXml.ToString()
        Return stream
    End Function
```

Hopefully, that helps someone else out.